# How do I find where the "-s" goes in verbs?

Tags: pronouns, subject-verb-agreement, conjugations

Which one is correct and why?

> 1. it make**s** me better
> 2. it**s** make me better
> 3. it**s** make**s** me better.

I'm confused about the *-s*.

Comment: "it make**s** me feel better" is the one you are looking for. Please edit your question explaining why you think the other options might be correct. Why do you think "it**s**" is a possible option?

Comment: Suggested reading: http://www.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm

Comment: "its" is a possessive adjective as in  " the house and its garden". See: http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-possessive-adjectives.php

Comment: You add -s or -es to a verb in present tense after he/she/it or a noun singular:  My friend lives nextdoor/Peter lives nextdoor/ He lives nextdoor.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find where the “-s” goes in verbs?

First off, **its** is not a verb: it's a pronoun. **Make** (or **makes**) is a verb.

Second off, per Peter's comment, "it makes me feel better" is a sentence that you would meet more often than "it makes me better", so probably it is the sentence you're looking for. They are different in meaning: "tt makes me better" means "this thing makes me a better person", and "it makes me feel better" means "this thing improves my physical and/or mental state".

---

> it makes me better

This one is correct. It has the third-person pronoun **it** as subject. The verb **make** assumes the form **makes**, because the subject is a singular third-person pronoun.

> They make me better. (no **s** ending, because the subject is plural: "they")
>
> You make me better. (no **s** ending, because the subject is a second-person pronoun: "you")
>
> Knowledge make**s** me better. (we add the **s** ending, because "knowledge" is a singular third-person noun)

---

> it**s** make me better

This sentence is very strange. Theoretically it could be grammatical, but it would be very untypical ([see this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76337/its-as-a-possessive-pronoun)). So it's safe to say that this sentence would be wrong in 99% of cases.

**Its** is usually used as a determiner: it needs to stand before some noun or noun phrase:

> **Its qualities** make me better. (Whose qualities? **Its** qualities)

---

Finally, we can make both **its** and **makes** to be present in a sentence:

> I like this wine. It**s** taste make**s** me feel better. (Whose taste? -  **Its**.) ("Taste" is a third-person singular noun, so we add the **s** ending to the verb: "make**s**")

---

P.S.

Per Damkerng's suggestion, what you need to google for is "Subject-Verb-Agreement".

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is..
 **It makes me better**

Let's say we are talking about cake.
Cake is not plural so we would use "*it*" - "**It** makes me better".
Also, this is a little hard to explain so I'm going to quote this..

"*The rule for subject-verb agreement when there is a multiple subject is this: If the multiple subjects are joined by and, then the verb is plural. If the multiple subjects are joined by or/nor then the verb is singular*"

Comment: Welcome to ELL! It might be worth pointing out (for complete clarity, since the OP appears confused) that *its* is not the plural of *it;* that's *they.*